# File checkin and checkout in Java

Tags: java, file, locking, checkin, vcs-checkout

I came across one interesting requirement, where we have to implement a checkin/checkout functionality using Java.
The requirement is when the user2 the open up the file for writing/updating he will be restricted if another user1 is also making changes in the same file. If not, the user2 is able to lock the file for editing by other user. He makes his changes and commits the file for the other user for updation.

Do you have came across similar sort of requirement? If yes please let us know how to implement solution around this problem.

I can think file locking and unlocking feature, however I am not too sure how could I implement that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to realize are Semaphores/Mutexs. Java already has Semaphores, see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Probably overkill for you but you can write your own Mutex with the synchronized Modifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with plain Java solution, you should probably look into [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

There will probably be open source libraries as well, which you can use to get the work done instead of implementing your own from scratch.

Probably [JGit](https://svnkit.com/) or [SVNKit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) or [jCVS](http://www.jcvs.org/)